# C# Polymorphism with generic type constraints

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

I'm creating an extended method for `IQueryable<Item>`, where `Item` is an entity of Entity Framework.

The extended method returns one or more property values in first row, or returns null if no rows found or the property value is null.

Here is the code:

```
internal static TResult FirstOrDefault<TResult>(this IQueryable<Item> items,
        Expression<Func<Item, TResult?>> selector, TResult defaultValue)
        where TResult : struct
{
    var ret = items.Select(selector).FirstOrDefault();

    if (ret == null || !ret.HasValue)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    return ret.Value;
}

internal static TResult FirstOrDefault<TResult>(this IQueryable<Item> items,
        Expression<Func<Item, TResult>> selector, TResult defaultValue)
        where TResult : class
{
    return items.Select(selector).FirstOrDefault() ?? defaultValue;
}
```

As the property may have value-type value, I decide to create two extended methods for value-type and reference-type.

But when I use the method (see below),

```
_dbContext.Items.Where(i => i.Id == '...').FirstOrDefault(i => i.Modified, DateTime.Now)
```

VS warns

> The type 'DateTime' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TResult' in the generic type or method 'EFExtensions.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable, Expresion>, TResult)'

I know this means VS try to compile this method with **second** extended method, and **DateTime** will violate `where TResult : class` constraint.

How can I make VS use **first** one without modifying method name?

OR is there any better way to achieve my goal?

Any answer will be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first method, the return type of the `Expression` is a nullable `TResult` so all you need to do is return that. This can be done with a cast:

```
_dbContext.Items
    .Where(i => i.Id == '...')
    .FirstOrDefault(i => (DateTime?)i.Modified, DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Solved & THANKS! Instead of casting, I make ``Modified`` property be ``DateTime?`` type.